# can't figure out my validation error

Tags: php, forms, validation

I have yet another question for you guys.  So I'm new to PHP and I'm trying validate my code when I came across these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: newUser[email] in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment_2\registration.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined index: newUser[ID] in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment_2\registration.php on line 66

Notice: Undefined index: newUser[password] in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment_2\registration.php on line 70
```

question is, I'm not too sure how to treat it because of my form name:(  As always, any help is very much appreciated :)

Here's my registration.php code

```
<html>
    <h4>
        <center>
            New User Registration
        </center>
    </h4>
    <body>

        <?php
        /*
         * What this code does, is it takes the users registration information, and stores it in a file.
         * After that what I hope to do is to retrive the same file when the user is on the login page and if 
         * the login matches whats in the file, then proceed to the invoice page.
         */
include "functions.inc";

    // Define the datafile to hold the $users array
    $datafile = "users.dat";

    // See if the user has submitted something
    if (array_key_exists('register', $_POST))
    {
        // Get the new user info
            $the_user = $_POST['newUser'];


// Load the file of users and store it in $users
        $users = arrayfile_to_array($datafile);


        // Validate user name and password
        if (user_exists($the_user['ID'], $users))
        {
            echo "User already exists!";
        }
        else
        {
            // If valid, save to the file of users
            $users[] = $the_user;
            array_to_arrayfile($users, $datafile);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!file_exists($datafile))  // Data file doesn't exist, so create it
        {
            $users = array();
            array_to_arrayfile($users, $datafile);
        }
    }
?>

        <?php
       // my defined error values 
      $errEmail    = "";
      $errUser     = "";
      $errPass     = "";


      if(isset($_POST["register"])){

        // Email validation
        if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]\w+(\.\w+)*\@\w+(\.[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/", $_POST["newUser[email]"]) === 0)
          $errEmail = '<p class="errText">Email must comply with this mask: chars(.chars)@chars(.chars).chars(2-4)</p>';
        // User must be digits and letters
        if(preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{5,}$/", $_POST["newUser[ID]"]) === 0)
          $errUser = '<p class="errText">User must be bigger that 5 chars and contain only digits, letters and underscore</p>';
        // Password must be strong
        //if(preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST["pass"]) === 0)
        if(preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $_POST["newUser[password]"]) === 0)
          $errPass = '<span class="error">Password must be at least 8 characters and must contain at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter and one digit</span>';
      }  
  ?>

        <form action = "<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method= 'POST'> 
            <center>
                <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td ><input name="newUser[ID]" type="text" size="16" value="">
          <?php  if(isset($errUser) and $errUser !='') echo $errUser; ?>
                        </td >
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="newUser[password]" type="password" size="16" value="">
          <?php  if(isset($errPass) and $errPass !='') echo $errPass; ?>
                        </td >
                    </tr>
                                         <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>:</td>
                        <td><input name="newUser[email]" type="text" size="50" value="">
          <?php  if(isset($errEmail) and $errEmail !='') echo $errEmail; ?>
                        </td >
                    </tr> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td> 
                    </tr>          
                </table>
                <input type='submit' name='register' value='Register'>
            </center>    
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to do a `vardump($_POST)` within the `if (isset($_POST["register"]))` block? What is the result of this? Also, consider looking at the function `empty()` instead of `isset() && != null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$_POST['newUser']['email']

Cheers

Comment: If this thing works, Christmas came early this year :)  Thanks! will try it out

Comment: Glad I could help. You could help me by accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `$_POST['newUser']['email']`.

But only for PHP though. In your form you can leave them without the quotes. Since that's HTML and not PHP. (I Think!)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response!  Going to try that right now and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: no luck:( gave me these errors:
Notice: Undefined index: newUser['email'] in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment_2\registration.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined index: newUser['ID'] in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment_2\registration.php on line 66

Notice: Undefined index: newUser['password'] in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment_2\registration.php on line 70

Comment: You may want a different approach though. In your form use names like `ID` and `password` without the `newUser` thing around it and just use `$_POST['password']` instead of `$_POST['newUser']['password']`. See if that helps. Oh, and try debugging your $_POST data by using `var_dump($_POST);` so you can see what is actually inside it.

Comment: I just now saw what you did with your $_POSt data. I've updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

I think you can not make an array directly through an HTML-Form and submit it as POST-Variables. You have to rename the variables in the HTML-Form. For example

```
<input name="newUser[password]" type="password" size="16" value="">
```

to

```
<input name="newUser_password" type="password" size="16" value="">
```

And the PHP accordingly:

```
$_POST["newUser_password"]
```

Comment: You can make an array from the HTML form to PHP, just throw `[]` after the name of the field and PHP puts it into an array.